# ActionChains in a loop causing stale element reference

Tags: python, selenium

This isn't the first time its happening, I am always forced to rewrite `actions[x] = ActionChains(browser)` with a different number every time. From what I understand, the state of the function doesn't override itself? Why is it storing a previous element click when I need it to click a new row in the loop? To put it more simply, I had 2 things I had to double click before. This is what I ended up with:

```
actions1 = ActionChains(browser)
actions1.double_click(button1).perform()

actions2 = ActionChains(browser)
actions2.double_click(button2).perform()
```

How am I supposed to make this work in a loop?

This is the actual code snippet.

```
tableRows = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div[1]/main/div/div/div[3]/div[5]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr')
for row in tableRows:
    actions1 = ActionChains(browser)
    actions1.double_click(row).perform()
    time.sleep(2)
    editEntity = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(editEntityCSS)
    editEntity.click()
    time.sleep(1)
    groupId = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(groupIdCSS)
    if groupId.text.isnumeric():
        kback = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#app > div.v-application--wrap > main > div > div > div.container > div:nth-child(3) > div > div > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > ul > li:nth-child(5) > div > div')
        kback.click()
        htree = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#app > div.v-application--wrap > main > div > div > div.container > div:nth-child(4) > div > div > div.row.no-gutters.align-start.justify-start.align-content-start > div:nth-child(1) > div > div > div.v-slide-group__wrapper > div > div:nth-child(3)')
        htree.click()
    else:
        deletegroup = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#app > div.v-application--wrap > main > div > div > div.container > div:nth-child(5) > div > div:nth-child(3) > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.ml-3.px-2.elevation-0.v-card.v-sheet.theme--light > div > div.col-md-4.col-12 > div > div > button')
        deletegroup.click()
```

Comment: How many rows does this represent `//*[@id="app"]/div[1]/main/div/div/div[3]/div[5]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr` ? You do not have to define `actions1`  or `actions2`, only 1 variable should sufficient,

Comment: about 15, it loops through those. I know 1 variable should be fine, but for some reason, its not